# SP2013 & Responsive Design - How to do it right?

Tags: 2013, boot-strap, responsive, device-channel

I'm a SharePoint developer and also skilled in web design. My current task is to implement a responsive design along with a branding in SharePoint 2013 environment

Now I am in the situation to choose which one I would use to implement a responsive design in SP2013 and so I collected **pro's** and **con's** for each technology.

What do you think? Are there important aspects I'm missing? Are there other solutions which are better suited for realizing this?

Answer (score 12):

### Device Channels

Yes I'm talking about `Device Channels` even when they are not mentioned in the question, because they can deliver the best performance and optimizability for the end user and the client - in my opinion :)

**Pro**

- individual designed `HTML/CSS` and `JS` foreach device
- -- no need for hiding or removing incompatible elements
- -- faster because you just load things you really need
- -- faster because you will likely have less `CSS/JS and HTML`
- -- faster because you can use optimized code foreach device
- -- you can better point out which channel has errors and changes don't affect the other channels

**Con**

- individual designed `HTML/CSS` and `JS` foreach device
- -- you have to append changes to each masterpage
- -- more work to accomplish the same result (in general)
- -- redundancy
- bound to `User Agent Strings`
- growing diversity of devices
- -- may equals growing diversity of masterpages >> work

---

### Bootstrap

**Pro**

- mighty, easy to use framework
- -- a lot of documentation
- -- fast results
- -- if you like it - all the Bootstrap styles
- there are already projects using it so you may don't have to build it from scratch
- -- http://responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com/

**Con**

- Bootstrap is a huge framework and has 8000+ lines of code in the unminified `CSS` and `JS` files
- -- 2 requests extra for ~ 130kb & 30kb
- -- a lot of styles and script for your browser to handle
- Bootstrap is not build for use in SharePoint
- -- it's overwriting SharePoint styles which makes some features (`ComposedLooks` for ex.) less valuable
- -- there are a lot of custom `CSS` needed to make it work seamless with SharePoint
- SharePoint has it's own weird way to do things and that interferes with Bootstrap
- -- tons of `CSS`
- -- tons of `JS`
- -- tons of `HTML Attributes`

---

### Media Queries

**Pro**

- only necessary `CSS`
- no `JS` if you don't wan't to
- you can create your own layout
- with `response.js` even in IE6 working
- you can easily separate which features should be available in certain screen sizes

**Con**

- several sets of `CSS` depending on the number of `Breakpoints`
- every feature needs to be developed by yourself
- it's not easy to write generic code that can process every SP2013 Page
- -- it depends on the complexity of the content shown. I write about 150 lines of `CSS` that created a mobile view for publishing pages that contained the navigation and content, but no features like editing, etc.
- -- if the client wants every feature on his smartphone, there is a hell lot of work and testing needed. (Plus who the hell wants to do that on their phone?)

---

### Conclusion

I'm not sure yet (and it would be awesome to get a lot of feedback to my results), but I tend to use `Media Queries`. Why ? Well SharePoint has it's own way to handle desktop users and I wouldn't customize that build in functionality if not explicit ordered. On the other hand SharePoint doesn't provide a real UI for smartphones. I don't want to use Bootstrap because it contains a lot of styling which will produce problems in branded environments. And I won't use `Device Channels` because of the downsides.

Comment: Just a tiny note from UX, on your phone you should have exactly the same features as on your desktop! Always! I don't know a thing about sharepoint, but developing different html for different devices sounds awfully lot like different features for different devices.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean! Those sites which wont give a smartphone full access and don't even contain a "to desktop version" link. But I would say SharePoint differs here a bit. In v.1 there will be a stripped version for smartphones, but I will also include a possibility to enter the full experience.

Comment: How much of your answer changes based on whether its a publishing site vs team site?

Comment: Because the theming of teamsites is more complicated than on publishingsites (inheritance, etc.) it's a diffrence. Even more when you think about the collaboration purpose.

I need to create a mobile version for both of them (and a lot of custom page layouts). A responsive design, that would contain all features the main page has would take years (in comparison) to develop, but when I just hide everything and then show the content the user needs to see, I can release an early v.1 and can easily add new elements if needed.

Comment: I did my website blog with sharepoint online and bootstrap, I used as a starting point the templates provided by Eric Overfield in his book. my site is here: http://levalencia-public.sharepoint.com/, his book is: http://www.amazon.com/Eric-Overfield/e/B00BYC7L4Q